# Documentation for Jagatoo

Tags: java

I can't find any documentation for Jagatoo, except for a single PDF in the doc folder. Is there any at all?

Would make it a lot easier to read about the structure, rather than investigating it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the source code.

Source code really is the best documentation in the absence of adequate documentation. I find that if I really want to wrap my head around a framework or library, the best thing to do is to dedicate an evening (or weekend, depending) to a proper *deep dive* of the source code. The added benefit is then that you know exactly where missing functionality needs to go if you want to implement it yourself, and better yet, contribute it back to the Open Source community.

PS I presumed you meant that the PDF on [this page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jagatoo/files/documentation/InputSystem/) is the only one you could find.
You could potentially also look at how [Xith3D](http://xith.org/) makes use of JAGaToo.

Comment: Thanks, guess that's what I need to do then.

Comment: "Source code really is the best documentation." No, it really isn't. Source code is the best documentation *only* if there is no adequate documentation in any other form.

Comment: Yes, with an emphasis on adequate. Answer amended :)